# Bitcoin Address Received/Balance values differ from one explorer to another

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, balance, watch-only

Recently I've been looking into experimenting with querying the blockchain. I am running bitcoin-core, full node locally and updated.

I am mainly interested in querying watch-only addresses, each address is saved under a unique label (one to one). After rescanning, I try to query a randomly chosen address with "getreceivedbyaddress" (in this case: 367f4YWz1VCFaqBqwbTrzwi2b1h2U3w1AF )

bitcoin-cli displays a value of approx. 171,500 BTC
blockexplorer.com displays the same value as the bitcoin-cli
blockcypher.com and blockchain.com display nearly the same value - 33,000 BTC (which could be due to latency issues)

I would like to know if this is an issue from my end or if there's something I do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

When I looked,

- one site said there were 120612 transactions
- one site said there were 120614 transactions

one site alerted me that there were unconfirmed transactions

I surmise this is a highly active address and that different sites may have differing delays and differing thresholds for confirmation.

As [Raghav](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/7272/raghav-sood) noted in a comment:

> another factor is that some explorer count change sent to the same address as an additional incoming btc tx, while others (blockchain.info) don't. It would explain such a large difference in this case, since the address seems to output a lot of change to itself.

Comment: I suspect another factor is that some explorer count change sent to the same address as an additional incoming btc tx, while others (blockchain.info) don't. It would explain such a large difference in this case, since the address seems to output a lot of change to itself.

Comment: I noticed the unconfirmed transactions and difference in transactions listed, however an approximately 140,000 difference in BTC is too much for that minor difference. What Raghav Sood said might make more sense and could be the culprit.

Comment: Agreed, answer updated accordingly.

Comment: Cannot upvote the answer due to rep, but thanks for the response!